# Other than Ocean, what other famous loaders were there?

Tags: commodore-64, gaming

Many people are familiar with the awesome `Ocean` loaders from the 8-bit days.

For those that are not, "loaders" are small programs that were usually artwork and music (sometimes games) that were displayed while the actual game loaded from tape or disk.

Ocean (a games publishing company) was famous for creating 5 (IIRC) loaders that they used in many of their games.

Were there any others that achieve nearly (or greater?) success and popularity as the Ocean loaders?

I'm mostly interested in the ones for `Commodore 64` but any other retro platform would be great.

---

I should have mentioned that "famous" doesn't always mean "legit".  :-)  So, if the loader was famous/well-known but belonged to a cracking group, that is also OK.

Comment: What are the `Ocean` loaders? I don't know about them. You could edit your question to explain if you wanted. As for the Commodore 64, many people made custom loaders to speed the disk drives up. I don't know if that's the sort of thing you mean.

Comment: Good point.  I edited my answer to explain what they are.

Comment: I remember Ocean loaders; I can't think of any equivalent, unless you look into the cracked games world and there were quite a few loaders we saw over and over on many games; but the Ocean one is the only 'non pirate' one I remember.

Comment: @Thomas good point.  I updated and mentioned cracks too.  While they may not be "legit", they certainly were famous.

Comment: http://csdb.dk/

Comment: Also the Paradox (PDX) demos come to mind, still rock `the HER-collection`, but that was for Amiga.

Comment: Things like [Invade-a-Load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invade-a-Load), for being memorable, or loaders that were common to a lot of games?  Certainly I remember spending a lot of time staring at the Electronic Arts logo while waiting for games to load, but that might not have been a lot of games; that might have just been one _really_ slow loader.

Comment: In the latter years of ZX Spectrum, custom loaders were quite widespread. Since the usual way was to load the intro screen first (so that you have something to stare at while the rest of the game loads), many loaders changed the way this screen is displayed, often by literally "drawing" the screen in 8x8 blocks in artfully designed directions.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.luigidifraia.com/c64/docs/tapeloaders.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember Invade-a-Load quite fondly (mostly for the music though you could play a fairly difficult game of Space Invaders whilst your game was loading).

[Invade-a-Load on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invade-a-Load)